# Impact on the battery life of a wireless mouse based on a using practice

Tags: batteries, wireless, mouse

While using a wireless mouse having alkaline batteries, does it matter to the life of batteries, at what distance from my computer I use it? I mean, if I use the wireless mouse from a far distance (within transmitter-receiver's recognisable range) will it drain the batteries more?

Answer (score 1):

It won't drain the batteries any quicker. Your mouse doesn't know how far it is from the receiver plugged in your computer.

Comment: That's not necessarily true in a practical sense.  If there's a *reliable* communication protocol such that unacknowledged messages are retransmitted until acknowledged or some give-up threshold, then being at marginal range would result in a lot more transmissions, and that will have an energy cost.  Many of these chipsets actually do measure RSSI. On the other hand, if the mouse just keeps blindly transmitting and hoping someone is listening, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: +1 For a bluetooth mouse, yes, but I haven't seen one of these for ages. For a standard 2.4GHz wireless mouse (with a USB receiver), there is only one-way communication between the mouse and the receiver on the PC.